# ATM protocol: VCI and VPI definition

Tags: protocol-theory, atm

I want to answer a past exams question with a clean/simple way about:

> Why does ATM protocol use for virtual circuit numbering both VPI
>   **and** VCI logical numbers?

From what I've understood: The VCI changes through the nodes that it goes through and VPI has the destination path.

I found this also: *The address is broken into a VCI and a VPI subfield.
Session following the same path for several nodes can be assigned the same VPI. Some switches only look at VPI, simplifying switch complexity.*

Can someone help me get this cleared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason--and I'm sure there are many, many more--is because you can have the same VCI on multiple different VPIs.

The VPI is 8 (OK, 8-12) bits, while the VCI is 16 bits. VPI 0 has VCI 35... but VPI 1 also has VCI 35, as does VPI 2. Guess what? VPI 3 also has a VCI 35. These VCIs don't necessarily interact.

This is probably more for the PVC (Permanent Virtual Circuit) implementation, common in ISP networks.

It's a bit like asking why you have a third AND a fourth octet in an IP address, or why you need a street AND city name in a postal address. ;)